# Erratic behavior of showsUserLocation in MKMapView

Tags: ios, ios5, mkmapview

I have an `MKMapView` with an `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem`. The user's current location should only be displayed in the `Follow` or `FollowWithHeading` modes. The implementation looks like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
didChangeUserTrackingMode:(MKUserTrackingMode)mode 
       animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:(mode != MKUserTrackingModeNone)]; 
}
```

This is the only place in my code where `setShowsUserLocation` is called and it works as expected when the `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` is pressed.

My problem occurs when the `UserTrackingMode` is changed by dragging the map: in this case, the "blue dot" annotation disappears as intended, but in about 20% of cases it reappears when dragging has ended.

If I then test for the map's `showsUserLocation` property, it is always set to NO, even though the "blue dot" annotation is visible.

I'd be very grateful for help if you know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like if a user location update comes in at a certain time during the drag, the `didUpdateUserLocation` delegate method still fires and the blue dot re-appears even though `showsUserLocation` is `NO`.

This appears to be a shortcoming of the map view.

Toggling `showsUserLocation` in `didUpdateUserLocation` seems to fix the map view's internal state and the blue dot goes away:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    if (!mapView.showsUserLocation)
    {
        mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
        mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
    }
}
```