# User location appearing when setshowsuserlocation = NO

Tags: ios5, mkmapview

I created a custom view for user location using :

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

if([annotation class]==[MKUserLocation class])
{
   //my code to return the pin
}
else
{
  //code for custom pin
}
```

After some user action i update setShowsUserLocation to NO for the mapview. Then I start core location controller which uses a different custom pin view to track user location. THe original pin dissappears for sometime but then reappears later on when i drag or pinch to zoom on the map. while debugging i saw that it enters the if condition above was called inspite of setShowsUserLocation being set to no.

Comment: For the "blue dot reappearing" problem, where exactly are you updating showsUserLocation to NO?  Try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555903/erratic-behavior-of-showsuserlocation-in-mkmapview.  Also, not your question but, note that supplying your own view for MKUserLocation has an issue (view no longer moves with user location).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432746/custom-annotation-view-for-userlocation-not-moving-the-mapview/11435874#11435874 for details and a workaround.

Comment: thank you. will implement the second solution as i need the view to move.